# Highlight all occurrences of text in different html tables on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found several solutions, but they all collect the 'search' text from an input field with an ID using *let text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;*.  I have twelve separate HTML tables set up in a grid (one for each month). Each HTML table is built from data collected from a MySql table. I just want to click on a table row and have any other matching row in any other table highlighted.  Each table has *class="in_year"*. I can get the text from the row when I click on it using:

```
$(".in_year tr").click(function(){
   var searchtext =  $(this).children("td:nth-child(n)").text();
   alert(searchtext);
});
```

The alert shows me the text in the selected row. I have tried to simply replace the input 'search field' in the other solutions with my *searchtext* variable, but nothing happens.
Of the solutions I've found, this one doesn't rely on an ID tag:

```
var searchword = $("#searchtxt").val();
var custfilter = new RegExp(searchword, "ig");
var repstr = "<span class='highlight'>" + searchword + "</span>";
if (searchword != "") {
    $('body').each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(custfilter, repstr));
    })
}
```

I replaced the first line with:

```
   var searchword =  $(this).children("td:nth-child(n)").text();
```

Still, nothing happens...

Comment: `:nth-child(n)` ?

Comment: I changed nth-child(n) to nth-child(1) to collect the first TD occurrence in the row instead of the entire contents of the row.  It had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using jquery 'contains()' :

```
$(".in_year tr").click(function(){
    $("td").removeClass("highlight");
    var searchtext =  $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)").text();
    $("td:contains('" + searchtext + "')").addClass("highlight");
});
```

The class .in_year is a div containing all of the tables. I find the text in the td being clicked and store it to 'searchtext'. Then I simply addClass .highlight all td's containing the 'searchtext' variable.